# jquery datetimepicker set to date depand on from date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datetime, datepicker

I am using jQuery "datetimepicker" and I want to set the "to date" value depend on the "from date" value and the Select box value which contains following values.

1- Weekly (7+ days)
2- Monthly (30+ days)
3- Half Yearly (6+ months)
3- Yearly (1+ Year)

Example:

1- Select From Date: 2015-05-29
2- Duration Monthly
3- To date should be 2015-06-29

I am using following code to select date start date.

```
jQuery('#start_date').datetimepicker({
    format:'m/d/Y',
    closeOnDateSelect:true,
    timepicker:false
});
```

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your other code depending on selecting Weekly, Monthly, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you have something like this:

a) a select box like this

```
Options : 
<select id="time">
    <option value="1">Weekly (7+ days)</option>
    <option value="2">Monthly (30+ days)</option>
    <option value="3">Half Yearly (6+ months)</option>
    <option value="4">Yearly (1+ Year)</option>
</select>
```

b) and two date pickers, like this:

```
Select From Date :
<input id="start_date" type="text" />
Select END Date :
<input id="end_date" type="text" />
```

c) the code for date-picker and onSelect function that will change the second date-picker:

```
/** addExtraTime() function 
*    this function changes the second datepicker ( $('#end_date').datepicker )
*    according to the selected value of select box.
*/
var addExtraTime = function (aDateObj) {
    var actualDate = aDateObj;
    var newDate = aDateObj;
    var extraTime = $('#time').val(); //string
    if (extraTime === '1') { //Weekly = +7d
        newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate() + 7);
        $('#end_date').datepicker('setDate', newDate);
    } else if (extraTime === '2') { //Monthly = +1m
        newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth() + 1, actualDate.getDate());
        $('#end_date').datepicker('setDate', newDate);
    } else if (extraTime === '3') { //Half Yearly = +6m
        newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth() + 6, actualDate.getDate());
        $('#end_date').datepicker('setDate', newDate);
    } else if (extraTime === '4') { //Yearly = +1y
        newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear() + 1, actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate());
        $('#end_date').datepicker('setDate', newDate);
    } //End of if..else
};

/* We watch for changes in the select box and call the addExtraTime() */
$('#time').change(function () {
    var currentDate = $('#start_date').datepicker("getDate");
    addExtraTime(currentDate);
});

/* From Date picker */
$('#start_date').datepicker({
    format: 'm/d/Y',
    closeOnDateSelect: true,
    timepicker: false,
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        /*
         * selectedDate is a string so we convert is to a Date obj
         */
        var selectedDateObj = new Date(selectedDate);
        addExtraTime(selectedDateObj);
    } //End of onSelect

});

/* To Date picker */
$('#end_date').datepicker({
    format: 'm/d/Y',
    closeOnDateSelect: true,
    timepicker: false
});
```

You can see this in action: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rtoaombf/2/)

Comment: Thanks Cubakos, but what if we change the Dropdown options? Could you please provide the event for it so it will change the end_date as per selected value.

Comment: @pratik you are welcome. I edited my answer to match what you ask. I moved the if..else statements outside of the onSelect function and into a function, so we can call it within the change function, we attached to our select box.